# link_to has no controller and no action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, link-to

I have a view with the following link generator:

```
- @tags.each do |tag|
  = link_to tag.name, :controller => "images", :action => "#{tag.name}"
```

`@tags` is `Tag.all`. It displays the links with the correct names, mouseover shows e.g.

```
http://localhost:3000/Images/tagname
```

but if I click on one the error is:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"", :action=>""}
```

How can it say `:controller` is empty when I specified `:controller => "images"`?

**rake routes (relevant part):**

```
images GET           /images(.:format)                     images#index
POST                 /images(.:format)                     images#create
new_image GET        /images/new(.:format)                 images#new
edit_image GET       /images/:id/edit(.:format)            images#edit
image GET            /images/:id(.:format)                 images#show
PUT                  /images/:id(.:format)                 images#update
DELETE               /images/:id(.:format)                 images#destroy
tags GET             /Images(.:format)                     tags#index
POST                 /Images(.:format)                     tags#create
new_tag GET          /Images/new(.:format)                 tags#new
edit_tag GET         /Images/:id/edit(.:format)            tags#edit
tag GET              /Images/:id(.:format)                 tags#show
PUT                  /Images/:id(.:format)                 tags#update
DELETE               /Images/:id(.:format)                 tags#destroy
```

One tag e.g. is "`saturn`", so I added this route too in `routes.rb`:

```
match '/Images/saturn'                => 'images#saturn'
```

which leads to:

```
Images_saturn        /Images/saturn(.:format)              images#saturn
```

I also have a method "`saturn`" in my images controller.

Comment: can you post the result of `rake routes` here?

Comment: more stack trace? quite possibly it's the view that you're linking *to* which contains the bad url helper method, not the view with these tag links. after all, if you had a routing error in this view, you'd get the error when you tried to load it, not when you tried to leave it.

Comment: I have added the rake routes results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you have a capitalization issue.  You have in your routes both /images and /Images ... Can you try fixing that?

Answer (score 0):

Try

= link_to tag.name, {:controller => "images", :action => "#{tag.name)}"}

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra ")" after

```
"#{tag.name)}"
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault, in the code it was correct. I have corrected it in the question above now.